# Find $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) + xf(1 - x) = 1 + x \forall x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: functional-equations

Find $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) + xf(1 - x) = 1 + x \space \forall \space x \in \mathbb R$

My solution:
$$f(x) + xf(1-x) = 1+x \space \space ..(i)$$
Substituting $x$ with $1-x$ we have,
$$f(1-x) + (1-x)f(x) = 2-x \space ..(ii)$$
Multiplying $(ii)$ by $x$ we have,
$$xf(1-x) + x(1-x)f(x) = x(2-x) \space ..(iii)$$
Now subtracting $(iii)$ from $(i)$,
$$f(x)+xf(1-x) - xf(1-x) - x(1-x)f(x) = 1+x - x(2-x)$$
$$\implies f(x) - x(1-x)f(x) = 1+x - x(2-x)$$
$$\implies f(x) - (x-x^2)f(x) = 1+x - (2x-x^2)$$
$$\implies f(x) + (-x+x^2)f(x) = 1 + x - 2x + x^2$$
$$\implies (1-x+x^2)f(x) = 1 - x + x^2$$
Dividing $(1-x+x^2)$ on both sides we have,
$$\therefore f(x) = 1$$

Please check if this solution is correct or not. I hope it is correct. If there is any other solution I would like to read it. Please feel free to answer.

PS: I don't know if there is any duplicate question or not but if it is there instead of flagging it please mention it in the comments.

Comment: It looks right. I would also add a comment that $1-x+x^2$ does not have real roots, so you can safely divide by it. Otherwise $f(x)$ can fave any value at those roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, but here is  a simpler way:
$$f(x)+xf(1-x)=1+x~~~(1)$$
Change $x \to 1-x$
$$f(1-x)+(1-x)f(x)=2-x$$
Take $f(x)=A, f(1-x)=B$, to write
$$A+xB=1+x ~\&~B+(1-x)A=2-x$$
Solve these two as linear equations of $A,B$, then get   $A=1=f(x), B=1=f(1-x)$.
Which means $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Man both the answers are essentially the same but thanks. Your way reduces the writing load and visualizes the answer nicely.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
$$f(x) + xf(1-x) = 1+x \space \space ..(i)$$
Substituting $x$ with $1-x$ we have,
$$f(1-x) + (1-x)f(x) = 2-x \space ..(ii)$$
Multiplying $(ii)$ by $x$ we have,
$$xf(1-x) + x(1-x)f(x) = x(2-x) \space ..(iii)$$
Now subtracting $(iii)$ from $(i)$,
$$f(x)+xf(1-x) - xf(1-x) - x(1-x)f(x) = 1+x - x(2-x)$$
$$\implies f(x) - x(1-x)f(x) = 1+x - x(2-x)$$
$$\implies f(x) - (x-x^2)f(x) = 1+x - (2x-x^2)$$
$$\implies f(x) + (-x+x^2)f(x) = 1 + x - 2x + x^2$$
$$\implies (1-x+x^2)f(x) = 1 - x + x^2$$
Dividing $(1-x+x^2)$ on both sides we have,
$$\therefore f(x) = 1$$